# CSS showing on local computer, but not on Heroku (Python, Django)

Tags: python, django

I have built a website using both bootstrap styling, and also a stylesheet for other changes I wish to make along the way.

I have it displaying a certain way on my local machine, but I can't get it refelected on my site.

Is there something that I need to add to my settings.py file to know that it should read the static css file?

[image: Correct styling image on local]

[image: Online Heroku styling]

**Here is my html file for this one:**

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title> Insure Need </title>
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-4 border">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'website:welcome' %}">InsureNeed</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'website:insureNeeds' %}">InsureNeed</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'website:learn' %}">Learn</a>
                </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'website:contact' %}">Contact</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


    </nav>
<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="pb-2 mb-2 border-bottom">
        {% block page_header %}{% endblock page_header %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </div>
</main>
<!--{% include 'website/footer.html' %}-->
</body>

</html>
```

```
    I also have this is my settings.py file:
    
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

Happy to edit and provide other needed info. Thanks Hayden

**Have tried:**
git init
git commit -am "message"
git push origin master
git status
git pull origin master

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets), you should use [WhiteNoice](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve tha statc files.

First install the WhiteNoise

```
pip install whitenoise
```

in your `settings.py` after `SecurityMiddleware` add `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    #...
]
```

and if you want forever-cacheable files you can add to your `settings.py`

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
```

Comment: Hey thanks Nardole - this worked (although I did have an issue with the second part you mentioned, so i just removed that), but thanks!

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?